# Can't find Play Framework Console in IDEA

Tags: playframework, intellij-idea

Where can I find Play Console in the latest IDEA ? According to **[this](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/01/play-console-in-intellij-idea/)** post I should have a menu option in Tools. I don't see it.

I'm using

- IntelliJ IDEA 129.111
- Play 2.0 Support Plugin 0.2.26
- Generic Playframework support Plugin
- Play Framework 2.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the **SBT** console (Play console is a wrapper on top of Sbt)

- Installation: http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=5007
- Wiki: https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/wiki

Comment: Okay. Where do I find it in IDEA ?

Comment: I've updated my response. You can obviously find it in the plugin repository.