# Play! 2.0 console in Intellij IDEA won't work

Tags: java, scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I asked this question yesterday, but it was marked as duplicate. So please read my question to the end, don't mark it as duplicate again!

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16004645/921193) to original question.

**Original question:**

I setup new Play 2.0 Framework project using Intellj IDEA. But I can't find how to run Play!'s command-line utility in Intellij IDEA. From tutorials I learn it must be accessible from `Tools | Play with Playframework`.

But I missed this context menu:

[image]

Where can my problem be?

Some additional info:

- I setup a new project using Intellij IDEA wizard.
- I'm  able to run the application from Intellij IDEA using the Run command and see the result in the browser.
- I'm using Intellij Idea 12.1.1
- **To be able to create new project from IDEA I installed all additional plugins (Play 2.0 plugin, Scala plugin)**

P.S. An answer to my previous question suggested I `Add framework support`. But I don't see the `Play2.0` facet in the list.

Comment: up for determination :)

Comment: Check the [answer to this comment](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/getting-started-with-play-20-in-intellij-idea-12/#comment-385620): *@Lev, it is supposed that you don’t need it anymore, and the IDE provides what you need (e.g. run, compile, etc).*  You can use the [SBT console](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15669232/104891) instead.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently `Play with Playframework` was an option available for first release of plugin for Play **1.x** (I'm guessing after reading the docs, I have no such option enabled, although I have all required plugins working for Play 2 in Idea 12).

Actually you don't need to use Intelli's kickstarter for creating Play projects anymore, all you need is:

- Create new project within command line:

  ```
  play new
  ```
- `idealize` it with command line too:

  ```
  play idea
  ```
- Go to Idea, choose `File` > `Open...`, find folder with app created in previous steps and... voilà!

Comment: You can also use the Typesafe Activator (http://typesafe.com/activator) to create Play projects.  That has many templates available to choose from.

Answer (score 4):

Play is using SBT console that will be available in the official SBT plugin for IntelliJ IDEA (to be released by the end of April 2013).

Right now you can use the third-party SBT plugin that also provides the console, [check this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669232/104891).

Also, as [answered in the blog](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/getting-started-with-play-20-in-intellij-idea-12/#comment-385620), *it is supposed that you don't need it anymore, and the IDE provides what you need (e.g. run, compile, etc)*.

Comment: It is supposed and actually I do not need it anymore except from one thing: I would like to start Play from IDEA as "play ~run" (saving file triggers compilation). How is it possible now?

Comment: Make a Run configuration for the Play app and remove Make from the Before Launch?

Comment: I don't have Make before launch. The difference is what triggers the compilation. With "play ~run" play starts compilation on file save. With "play run" the triggers is page refresh.

Comment: Can you provide some info about SBT plugin for IntelliJ IDEA? What is status of plugin? Can we expect it in Intellij IDEA 12 release? Or it delayed to 13 release of IDEA? Thanks

Comment: @MyTitle, developers say that the first SBT plug-in version will be available soon, probably this week, but it's not certain if the console will be included in this build. Stay tuned and feel free to post your questions in [the forum](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/community/idea/scala).

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, using Play's console in Idea is not obvious.

What you need to do is:

- In your toolbar, there's a select box (it's written *run* on yours), click it and choose *Edit configurations*
- On the upper left, click the plus (*+*) sign
- Choose *Play 2 App*
- Configure it as you wish
  You may need to remove *make* from the *Before launch* box. Not sure why, but it doesn't let my Play start.
- Confirm

You can now launch Play's console from that little green *launch* button, next to the configurations selectbox.

I don't remember needing to run `play idea`, but do it anyway just in case.